# stop a calling script upon error

Tags: bash, error-handling

I have 2 shell scripts, namely script A and script B.
I have both of them "set -e", telling them to stop upon error.

However, when script A call script B, and script B had an error and stopped, script A didn't stop.

What can I stop the mother script when the child script dies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work as you'd expect. For example:

In `mother.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
./child.sh
echo "you should not see this (a.sh)"
```

In `child.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
ls &> /dev/null # good cmd
ls /path/that/does/not/exist &> /dev/null # bad cmd
echo "you should not see this (b.sh)"
```

Calling `mother.sh`:

```
[me@home]$ ./mother.sh
++ ./child.sh
+++ ls
+++ ls /path/that/does/not/exist
```

#### Why is it not working for you?

One possible situation where it won't work as expected is if you specified `-e` in the shabang line (`#!/bin/bash -e`) and passed the script directly to `bash` which will treat that as a comment.

For example, if we change `mother.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
./child.sh
echo "you should not see this (a.sh)"
```

Notice how it behaves differently depending on how you call it:

```
[me@home]$ ./mother.sh
+ ./child.sh
+ ls
+ ls /path/that/does/not/exist

[me@home]$ bash mother.sh  
+ ls
+ ls /path/that/does/not/exist
you should not see this (a.sh)
```

Explicitly calling `set -e` within the script will solve this problem.

Comment: Note for those who did not know (I didn't), -x is the debugging flag, @see: http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x4983.html